# Recompiled QEMU with OpenGL, but virt-manager or libvirt tells me This QEMU doesn't support spice OpenGL

Tags: debian, virtualization, gpu, qemu, opengl

I wanna to use virtio-gpu according to this blog:

https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2016/09/using-virtio-gpu-with-libvirt-and-spice/

I am using Debian testing, but QEMU in offical debian source is not support OpenGL
when I ran

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -display sdl,gl=on
```

it said

```
SDL1 display code has no opengl support.
Please recompile qemu with SDL2, using
./configure --enable-sdl --with-sdlabi=2.0
qemu-system-x86_64: OpenGL support is disabled
```

so I recompiled QEMU with these options.

After success, when I ran

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -display sdl,gl=on
```

again, it started a windows and continued.

But when I added

```
<graphics type='spice'>
  <listen type='none'/>
  <gl enable='yes'/>
</graphics>
<video>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</video>
```

to my libvirt domian file and started, libvirt prompt:

```
error: Failed to start domain debian9-xfce
error: unsupported configuration: This QEMU doesn't support spice OpenGL
```

I have already installed these package:

```
gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-3.0=0.33-3.3
libspice-server1=0.13.90-0.2
libvirglrenderer0=0.6.0-2
mesa-utils=8.3.0-5
libepoxy0=1.3.1-3
```

I spotted [there](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2016-February/msg01034.html) is a libvirt patch for QEMU OpenGL support:

```
+    if (graphics->data.spice.gl) {
+        if (!virQEMUCapsGet(qemuCaps, QEMU_CAPS_SPICE_GL)) {
+            virReportError(VIR_ERR_CONFIG_UNSUPPORTED, "%s",
+                           _("This QEMU doesn't support spice OpenGL"));
+            goto error;
+        }
```

But I don't know how does `virQEMUCapsGet` work to get QEMU capabilities because I have already compile QEMU with OpenGL support.

Comment: Wild guess: you installed your custom built qemu in `/usr/local/bin` and virtual machine manager is using the one in `/usr/bin`. I believe there's a way to edit the machine's XML to use a different qemu but I don't know the details.